# Как отлаживать Silverlight под VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, silverlight

Точки останова не работают, загруженные модули не определяются (список пуст). При этом 2012я версия студии нормально работала на другом компьютере.

Симптомы:

При попытке присоединиться к процессу студия определяет его тип как CoreCLR вместо Silverlight (2012я студия определяла тип процесса корректно):

[image]

Наверное, это как-то связано с тем что типа Silverlight в списке нет вообще.

Файл Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe я ставил, не помогло. Единственное изменение - теперь Firefox говорит что плагин устарел и его нужно срочно обновлять.

Версия firefox: ESR 52.4.1 (64-бит).
В IE проблема также воспроизводится.